# simulate atomic operation in independent systems

Tags: algorithm, atomic

I have two independent systems. At some point I would like to be able to make an operation that affects the both system, and I would like to simulate atomicity even this is technically impossible. To illustrate the problem lets say that we would like to move a object from one of the system to the other.

First because every operation might fail at any point I am adding a tentative record to the both system indicating the intention. The algo is:

1. Set the object in system 1 in tentative mode for remove
2. Set the object in system 2 in tentative mode for add
3. Move the object from system 1 to system 2
4. Remove the tentativeness from the system 2
5. Remove the tentativeness from system 1

The lack of atomic operation though might result in having the object in both systems are in none depending on the order of steps 4 and 5, and a crash between them.

My question is, is there an algorithm that could somehow resolve the lack of atomicity and allow me to guarantee it. I kind of see that it seems impossible, but I hope it is not.

Comment: Usually things like that are done using two-phase commit - transaction manager requests both systems whether they confirm they are ready to "finalize" tentative action, and after both agreed, send a command to do so.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on both systems - what are they? What's the way they handle an object in 'tentative' mode? Can it be seen while it's tentative? Does it become 'untentative' after a while?

Comment: The systems handle tentative states when the graceful handle of the tentative state timeout - the systems was unable to finish the whole operation - with checking the current state of the objects and restoring the proper presentation. The object can be seen, but some subset of operation are not allowed - depending on what is tentative - they might have different tentative flags enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible (though not perfect). Databases do this all the time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol for an introduction.

It is, of course, a pithy subject, so I can't supply a quick thumbnail sketch in code. But yes, you can do this.

Your approach has some merit. What you need is more communication between the two systems.

Comment: Not a bad idea, @DavidEisenstat. A database would fit nicely here, I think. And yes, it's an invasive change. But a) OP asked if it was possible, not if it was easy, and b) it's less onerous than simply pretending that it can't be done.